# Creating Multi SharePoint Pages Code

Tags: sharepoint, properties, web-parts, publishing

Create Publishing page on sharepoint using C# code and adding a webpart which contains webpart properties pane.

Need help in that because I have to make a lot of pages.

Comment: Ok, so what is the question here?

Comment: how to create publishing sharepoint page via C#, also add a webpart into that page and set the properties for that webpart ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is by using Power shell.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that's the whole answer. Can you explain your answer a bit more?